# Qt Accessible Widgets

Tags: qt, accessibility

I'm trying to implement accessibility for my Qt application. I'm using NVDA (http://www.nvda-project.org/) and Freedom Scientific's JAWS (http://www.freedomscientific.com/products/fs/jaws-product-page.asp) as the screen readers I want to support.

I'm assigning the widget's accessibleName and accessibleDescription properties ([http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html#accessibleDescription-prop](http://ttp://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html#accessibleDescription-prop)) in order to get the screen reader to read this information.

Example:

```
saveButton->setAccessibleName("save");
saveButton->setAccessibleDescription("Save the options you have entered above");
```

In both screen readers everything is working correctly when using the mouse. However, when focus changes in a widget all the readers read is "pane". Why isn't Qt providing the accessibility information that I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import a plug-in to get Qt to have accessible widgets. This lets screen readers read the names, and hierarchies of objects.

To get this, you need to add qtaccessible widgets to your qmake project file:

```
QTPLUGIN += qtaccessiblewidgets
```

And in main.cpp add a Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN

```
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qtaccessiblewidgets)
```

Then screen readers will be able to accurately read:

> "Button. Save. Save the options you have entered above. Press space to activate the button."

When you tab to (or otherwise place focus on) a button

Answer (score -1):

in a tutorial video I saw that Qt surface components
have the properties "AccessibleName" and "AccessibleDescription".
This suggests that Qt applications are screen readable
can be developed. In the programming languages ​​are called Java and C #
the properties the same.
I am developing Python on Windows 10

Question:
Is there a guide on how to make a Python Qt application suitable for screen readers?

Comment: The OP already knows that it is possible in general with Qt and about those two properties. The question mentions them in text and source code.

Comment: If _you_ have questions yourself please post them as questions to the site. Thank you.